# Heroku "failed to compile" with heroku/python build pack, with no signs of pip running

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I am developing a Python app using `aiohttp` and `redis` to run in Heroku. It is deployed to Heroku via GitHub. Although there is no problem running the app locally, it fails to build in Heroku with the following error.

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.5.2
 !     Requested runtime (python-3.5.2
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Since the build is aborted before pip even has a chance to run, I'm not quite sure what has gone wrong. `runtime.txt` is copied off from a separate Heroku app which builds fine, and I can't find any problems in my `requirements.txt`.

My `requirements.txt` is:

```
aiohttp==0.21.6
redis==2.10.5
```

My `runtime.txt` is:

```
python-3.5.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I had the same issue as you did. If you look closely you see:

```
Requested runtime (python-3.5.2
```

Notice the "(". Probably has something to do with the encoding of the file. In Ubuntu I used dos2unix (apt-get install dos2unix && dos2unix runtime.txt) which solved this issue. Alternatively you could probably adjust settings in your favorite text editor / IDE. Atleast you'll know where to look.